# Getting balance in new Column by adding previous balance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need this type of view

[image]

[image]

Hello,

Currently i am developing an accounting software for my client. I got to solve an issue. I have two columns. debit and credit. i have to generate additional column balance by getting opening balance and adding and subtracting. Please help

Comment: what you need is a computed column, take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Or you just define a view or build a select and add the computed column in your select

Comment: Thanks . i just looking through the link.

Comment: What's your SQL Server release? Looks like you need a *Cumulative Sum* which is supported since SS2012: `SUM(credit - debit) OVER (PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY transactionno)`

Comment: i am using sql server 2014 express.. i added one more screen shot to know what specifically i needed.

Comment: The screen shot shows what you currently got, but not what you  want :)

Comment: dnoeth... no... i taken screenshot of another software :) . i am just referencing different software and implementing some features.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a *Cumulative Sum* which is supported since SS2012:

```
SUM(credit - debit) 
OVER (PARTITION BY account_id 
      ORDER BY transactionno
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS balance
```

This also works without ROWS, but then it defaults to RANGE which needs more resources to calculate.